# Simple angular app is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create basic angular app and it throws an error

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);
        angularApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=Ctrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Sb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:22:18)
    at Qa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:22:105)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:79:497
    at x (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:59:501)
    at S (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:60:341)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:54:384)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:53:444
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:19:481'
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must give `ng-app` the name of your app:

```
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="Ctrl"></div>
```

Comment: The reason this is needed is because if you don't supply a module name as the value for the `ng-app` attribute, Angular only bootstraps the included core `ng` module. Since the OP defined the `Ctrl` controller in their own custom module, they had to specify to load their module as well as the `ng` one (which gets loaded automatically regardless of whether you specify it or not).